# where do i put `just now` in a sentence i just now posted a blog to discuss something

Tags: meaning

on this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3242064/649828), i was telling someone a blog i posted.

here are a list of expressions

1. i just now posted a blog to discuss something.
2. i just posted a blog to discuss something.
3. i posted a blog to discuss something just now.
4. i posted a blog just now to discuss something.

which expression is more easy to understand and clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All four are acceptable in colloquial English, though 3. implies that your purpose is *to discuss something now*, rather than *posting the blog now*. Is that the intent?

Note that the personal pronoun `I` should **always** be capitalized!